# Limit mongoose returning owner object with child array

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Im sure this is around somewhere, ive read through both MongoDB documentation and some chunks of mongoose but I'm just trying to work out how to limit the result of a populate so it doesnt attempt to get the whole user aswell, just the child array.

I have 2 schemas dictating 2 collections, 'Question' and 'User', when I add a question, the user that made it gets assigned it, now I want to retrieve all questions they have, but when I do it also returns the whole owner object which I dont want as its a waste of computing and I am aware of the user already as they made the request.

Here is the result:
[image]
I simply want to get the 'questions' array, but not just filter out the result if possible, but stop asking for the whole user to start with, here is my mongoose query:

```
if (req.body.action == 'q_get') {
            var idtoken = req.body.idtoken;
            settings.userPayload(idtoken).then((result) => {
                if (result) {
                    USER.findOne({'unique_id': result['sub']})
                        .populate('questions')
                        .exec(function (err, questionsResult) {
                            if (err) return console.log(err);
                            res.json(questionsResult);
                        });
                } else {
                    res.json({result: 'failed to validate session'});
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 separate collections you can query them the same way. Instead of User.find() use Question.find() and filter using the user id or whatever you have that links them. But the output that you have looks like Questions are sub documents of the user so you will have to use a parent child related query or filter the query excluding everything but the sub document.

example for parent child document query: User.Question[0];. I am not sure yet how to efficiently get multiple sub documents. But this should get you started.

example for parent child query by id: User.Question.id(_id); Where _id can be a parameter in the url or from the body.